# Issues displaying output from compiled file executed in a Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, express

I have a web page with a file upload and a submit button. Upon submission, a Docker container is initiated to compile and run a C++ file uploaded by the user. The goal is to display the output of the program on the web server. Initially, I encountered issues with non-printable characters in the output displayed on the server.

To resolve this, I opted to save the output to a text file within the container. However, I'm facing an issue where the file appears to be created, but my Node.js server encounters an "ENOENT" (no such file or directory) error when attempting to read it.

The error message I'm encountering:

```
Error reading the file: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/slava/Desktop/TESTING/output/output.txt'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/home/slava/Desktop/TESTING/output/output.txt'
}
```

Interestingly, when I comment out the lines that stop and remove the Docker container (await container.stop(); and await container.remove();), the output is displayed correctly. However, I need to stop and remove the container after each use.

It seems that the file is created on the host machine, but my Node.js code doesn't recognize it until the second submission due to the container cleanup. Is there a way to ensure proper file handling and container cleanup without compromising the display of the output?

I appreciate any insights or alternative approaches to resolve this issue.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Set environment variables to avoid interactive prompts during installation
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Update and install essential packages
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \     
    cmake \               
    gdb \     
    g++ 

RUN mkdir /output && chmod 777 /output

# Copy the C++ code into the container
COPY submissions/ /submissions/ 

# Define an entry point script that will be executed by the Node.js server
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
```

**Entrypoint.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <source_code_file.cpp>"
    exit 1
fi

g++ -o user_program "$1" 

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    ./user_program > /output/output.txt 
else
    echo "Compilation failed." >&2
fi
```

**server.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const Docker = require('dockerode');
const docker = new Docker();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static('output'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        const userDirectory = `submissions/${req.body.username}`;
        fs.mkdirSync(userDirectory, { recursive: true });
        cb(null, userDirectory);
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.use(express.json());

process.chdir(__dirname);

app.post('/execute', upload.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
    const { code } = req.body;

    if (req.file) {
        const userDirectory = `/submissions/${req.body.username}`;

        const uploadedFilePath = path.join(userDirectory, req.file.originalname);

        const codeFileName = path.basename(uploadedFilePath, path.extname(uploadedFilePath));

        const container = await docker.createContainer({
            Image: 'my-cpp-app',
            Tty: true,
            Detach: true,
            HostConfig: {
                Binds: [
                    `${__dirname}/submissions:/submissions`,
                    `${__dirname}/output:/output`,
                ],
            },
        });

        await container.start();

        const sourceCodeFile = `/submissions/${req.body.username}/${req.file.originalname}`;
        const command = `/entrypoint.sh "${sourceCodeFile}"`;

        const exec = await container.exec({
            Cmd: ['bash', '-c', command]
        });

        const execResult = await exec.start();
        
        if (execResult.output) {
            await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                container.modem.demuxStream(execResult.output, process.stdout, process.stderr);
                execResult.output.on('end', resolve);
                execResult.output.on('error', reject);
            });
        }
        
        fs.readFile(`${__dirname}/output/output.txt`, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error reading the file:', err);
                return;
            }
            
            res.send({output:data});
        });
        
        await container.stop();

        await container.remove();
        
    }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Code Execution</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <h1>Upload and Execute Code</h1>
        <form action="/execute" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="code-form">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
            <br>
            <label for="file">File:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <h2>Code Execution Results</h2>
        <pre id="output" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('code-form').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            const formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('code-form'));
            fetch('http://localhost:3000/execute', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData,
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    document.getElementById('output').innerText = data.output;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    document.getElementById('output').innerText = 'An error occurred: ' + error.message;
                });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**C++ code that I used to test:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (void) {
cout << "Hello World";
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not running the entrypoint as the main container command.  Instead, you're running it in a secondary debugging process attached to the container.  In normal use you shouldn't need `container.exec()`.

In your Dockerfile you don't set any sort of `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`.  That means it's inheriting from the `ubuntu` base image, so it's running an interactive shell and waiting (because `Tty: true`) for you to enter something.

When you create the container, instead specify the `Cmd:` there.  (You probably don't need the `Tty:` option.)

```js
const sourceCodeFile = `/submissions/${req.body.username}/${req.file.originalname}`;
const command = ['/entrypoint.sh', sourceCodeFile];
const container = await docker.createContainer({
    Image: 'my-cpp-app',
    Cmd: command,
    Detach: true,
    HostConfig: {
        Binds: [
            `${__dirname}/submissions:/submissions`,
            `${__dirname}/output:/output`,
        ],
    },
});
```

Remove the entire `exec` setup; you don't need it.

Look for the output file after you've stopped the container.  Since it's on the host system, it should still be there after you've removed the container as well.

**If you're using Docker, be very careful with basic security concerns.**  What happens if the `username` request-body parameter is `../../../../../etc`, for example?  In this setup I've changed the command from a string to an array to minimize the risk of string-injection attacks (what if the caller-provided filename includes a `;` in the middle?) but you need a lot more input validation, and you probably need some limits on what exactly the process is allowed to do.

Comment: Thank you for the response, it works perfectly now!